# Consider the parametric curve given by: $x=3\cos(t)$, $y=t^{3/2}$.

Tags: parametric

The question asks to find the equation of the tangent to this curve at the point $t=\pi/4$.

I've determined $$\frac{dy}{dx} =(\frac{dy}{dt})/(\frac{dx}{dt}) = -0.222$$ Have I got the right idea?

Also asks for the solution to be in the form $y=mx+c$, thank you.

Comment: yes you are correct so far. So assuming that you are looking to also solve for the line, you can use your previous knowledge of how to obtain the equation given the gradient $m$ and a point i.e. $(x,y)$ at which the curve must intersect.

Comment: as far as I understand, m=gradient=-0.222, and c=y-intercept, but how do I figure out the y-intercept in this case?

Comment: there is an answer down below. But essentially you have $x(\pi/4),y(\pi/4)$  and with $m$ leaves only one unknown.

Comment: using that method I get c=(pi/4)^(3/2), therefore y=-0.222x+(pi/4)^(3/2), but it's saying the solution is incorrect, can you confirm that the answer's are correct? or have I made a mistake

Comment: Indeed, I don't get what you got also. what did you get for $x$ and $y$? also did you confirm that the gradient was correct?

Comment: It would be great if you also told us on which interval this curve is defined.

Comment: @AidanLeith general comment: check [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) reference guide for how to format math on this site--as is it's sort of unreadable.

Comment: @Aidan: You might add the details of how you computed the slope of the tangent line, since the slope should come out to $-\sqrt{\pi/8} \approx -0.6266...$.

Answer (score 1):

first find the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point at time $t = \pi/4.$ we have $x(\pi/4) = 3\sqrt 2/2 = 2.121, y = \left(\frac{\pi}4\right)^{3/2} = 0.696.$

now evaluate the slope at this point  $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}\big|_{t = \pi/4} = \frac{-3\sin \pi/4}{3\sqrt 2/2} = -1$$ therefore the tangent line at $t = \pi/4$ is $$y-0.696 = -1(x -2.121)\to y = 2.817-x $$

Answer (score 0):

The direction vector of the tangent you're looking for is given by $(\frac{\mathbb d x}{\mathbb d t},\frac{\mathbb d y}{\mathbb d t})$, evaluated in $\frac \pi 4$. Then you can determine $m$. Finally you deduce $c$ by taking $t = \frac \pi 4$ : since $(x(\frac \pi 4),y(\frac \pi 4))$ is a point of the tangent, $y(\frac \pi 4) = m x(\frac \pi 4) + c$.

Comment: using this solution I get c=(pi/4)^(3/2), but inputting this solution (y=-0.222x+(pi/4)^(3/2), says that the solution is wrong, can you confirm I've done the question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**: The usual way of finding a tangent line to a parametric curve $(x(t), y(t))$ at some number $t_{0}$ is to compute

- A *point* on the line, such as the point of tangency $(x_{0}, y_{0}) = (x(t_{0}), y(t_{0}))$.
- The *slope* of the tangent line, which is $m = y'(t_{0})/x'(t_{0})$ if $x'(t_{0}) \neq 0$.

Then use the point-slope form
$$
y - y_{0} = m(x - x_{0}),\quad\text{or}\quad
y = mx + (y_{0} - mx_{0}).
$$